# Question on eigenvalues of the power of matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{C})$ and $\{\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_k\}$ be the total set of eigenvalues of $A$. Then I suppose that for any $i\ge 2$, the set of eigen-values of $A^i$ would not equal to$\{\lambda_1^i,\cdots,\lambda_k^i\}$.

Is there any counter-example for this?

Let me ask one more question in this spirit.

I know if $\lambda\in F$ is a eigenvalue of $A$, then for any $k\ge 2$, $V_{A,\lambda} \subset V_{A^k,\lambda^k}$. (here, $V_{A,\lambda}$ is the eigenspace of $A$ with respect to $\lambda$.)

Do you know some counterexample such that $V_{A,\lambda} \ne V_{A^k,\lambda^k}$?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If $A=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}$ then $V_{A,1}$ is $1$-dimensional, but $V_{A^2,1^2}$ is $2$-dimensional.

Comment: Thank you very much! The second question is nice answered. But your example does not give a counter-example of the first question. Because 
 the set of eigenvalues of $A$ is $\{1,-1\}$ and the set for $A^2$ is $\{1\}=\{1^2, (-1)^2\}$. What is the counter example of the first question?